# Virtues of Surahs based on weak hadiths

Tags: quran, hadith, uloom-al-hadith, islamic-scholar

Asscalamualikum.

So I'm kinda confused about using weak hadiths. I looked into it and I understand that you can use weak hadiths for virtues of deeds and stuff to motivate and encourage people to do good, but I'm confused about reading surahs from the Qur'an at spefic times based on weak hadiths.

For example surah Waqiah before sleeping will get rid of poverty. Can we follow such hadiths? I saw in Ibn Hajars and Imam An Nawawis book, they mentioned this hadith, but now I'm confused.

It makes more sense that a deed has to be proven from a Sahih or Hasan hadith, then it can be supported using weak hadiths to encourage people to do it. Let's say theirs a weak hadith about if you pray 5 times, you will get Paradise or some, it makes sense bec the deed of salah 5 times is already proven from Sahih hadiths. But to say well we can recite so and so surah at so and so time for example before sleep, after eating, etc., based only on a weak hadith, doesn't make any sense to me. Bec the deed isnt proven from even a hasan hadith, so how can one follow that?

Can a weak hasith prove a deed like that? Thing is I'm confused about "virtues of deeds" does spefic surahs come under that at spefic times? It makes sense that you cant add a prayer on a weak hadith, but how come you can add a surah at a spefic time?

I get that duas can be recited from weak hadiths, but surahs at spefic times? It doesn't make any sense to me.

Please do explain this matter, I'm really confused. Jazakallah Khryran.

Comment: Relevant: [sunnah.com/virtues](https://sunnah.com/virtues)